# dataTables - add row in specified position

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can you set the fnAddData to add the row in a specified position.. eg. as the second row from the top?

```
var giCount = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    giCount+".4" ]
  );

  giCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position is specified by the sorting that is applied to the table - i.e. the data that add to the table is sorted equally along with all the other data in the table. So if you want it to go into a given position, then the data in the row needs to account for that, and the sort will position it.